# Linear Operators Problem

Tags: functional-analysis

Can someone help me with this one, please?

X is a real vector space, E$\subset$X a linear subspace and $f_1,f_2,...,f_n, n\ge 3$ linear applications on E such that:

$|f_1(e)|+|f_2(e)|+...+|f_n(e)|\le||e||, \forall e\in E$

Show that there is a constant M and the linear applications $\hat f_k$ defined on X, $1\le k\le n $, which extend $f_k$ such that:

$|\hat f_1(x)|+|\hat f_2(x)|+...+|\hat f_n(x)| \le M||x||, \forall x\in X$

How small M can be?

Comment: it is asking you to say that $X = E \oplus E^{\perp}$, and that for example $\hat{f}_k(e+u) = f_k(e)$ for every $(e,u) \in E \times E^{\perp}$.

Comment: wait, you wrote functional-analysis, maybe $\|.\|$ denotes a Banach space norm ? do you know Banach spaces and the Hahn-Banach theorem ?

Comment: I also thought about Hahn-Banach Theorem when I saw this problem. But I need some extra hints on how to use it on this

Comment: see 'Hahn–Banach Theorem (Rudin 1991, Th. 3.2)'  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Formulation. since $E$ is a linear subspace of $X$, $|f_k(e)| \le \|e\|$ for every $e \in E$ and $x\to \|x\|$ is sublinear $X \to \mathbb{R}^+$, then there exists $\hat{f}_k : X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\hat{f}_k(e) = f_k(e)$ for every $e \in E$ and $|\hat{f}_k(x)| \le \|x\|$ for every $x\in X$

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it seems crystal clear :) I wonder how small M can be

Comment: but what you have to remember of Hahn-Banach is that if $T$ is a linear operator $E \to Y$ then there exists $T_2 : X \to Y$ extending $T$ such that $\|T_2\| = \|T\|$ (the operator norm)

Comment: and for $M$, maybe you could consider $g(e) = \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(e)$ hence $\hat{g}(e) \le \|e\|$ ... but I'm not if it helps